# Hover getting automatically disabled in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, hover

Since few days, the hover popup in my VSCode gets disabled automatically for the current user.
Basically, the property `@id:editor.hover.enabled hover` is unset for User, but remains checked for Workspace.

Anyone of you started facing this issue recently?

These are the list of extensions I'm using:

```
    albert.TabOut
    amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode
    BrijeshBumrela.bhailang-extension
    cweijan.vscode-database-client2
    cweijan.vscode-office
    dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
    donjayamanne.typescript-notebook
    eamodio.gitlens
    GrapeCity.gc-excelviewer
    jsayol.firebase-explorer
    kevinglasson.cornflakes-linter
    mintlify.document
    ms-azuretools.vscode-docker
    ms-python.python
    ms-python.vscode-pylance
    ms-toolsai.jupyter
    ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap
    ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers
    ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers
    ms-vscode.cpptools
    ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next
    natqe.reload
    RandomFractalsInc.vscode-data-preview
    redhat.java
    redhat.vscode-yaml
    sourcery.sourcery
    TabNine.tabnine-vscode
    VisualStudioExptTeam.intellicode-api-usage-examples
    VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode
    vscjava.vscode-java-debug
    vscjava.vscode-java-dependency
    vscjava.vscode-java-pack
    vscjava.vscode-java-test
    vscjava.vscode-lombok
    vscjava.vscode-maven
```

I tried setting the key manually and it works, but couldn't figure out why it gets unset in the first place. Have done enough google search, but none reported this issue

Comment: Am also seeing this and it's driving me crazy. See the GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/165988

Comment: @Sean: Thanks for the issue link. Let's hope this gets resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause has been identified here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/165988#issuecomment-1329367779

It's caused by AWS Toolkit (CodeWhisperer).
Have cut an issue with them to get it fixed: https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode/issues/3014

Will update once the fix is rolled out by them

Update:
**The issue is fixed as of AWSToolkit 1.60.0**

Answer (score 0):

It is due to RedHat VSCode extension, you can view it in Output > Log (Window) terminal. Can't even remove the extension as thats required to read JUnit test cases.

Note : I wanted to add a commit, but don't have enough reputation to add a comment. Please don't downwote.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Let me check if it's the same culprit for me too. Also, did you figure out an alternative way to fix it then?